# A more comprehensive list of Voice Actions keywords?

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command

The formal Voice Actions [web page](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/) lists a small number of Voice Actions keywords:

1. send text to
2. navigate to
3. call
4. map of
5. note to self
6. listen to
7. send email to
8. go to
9. {anything else} fires Google Search?

But when I use certain applications which use Android's built-in speech recognition, the recognizer won't respond to certain **other** keywords as well. Instead, it will **wait** until a second word will be spoken before acknowledging "end of speech" and returning with a result (often the wrong one, because it's always the 1st word **plus** the 2nd word).

The fact that the returned result always includes the 1st word tells me that Google's recognizer **heard it**, but decided to ignore it for some reason. So the only explanation I can think of for now is that these must be "reserved keywords".

For example, two common such keywords I found to be exhibiting this behavior are: `open` and `exit` .

Have you experienced this too?

If so, with which words?

**Update:** I just observed that some phones are more prone to this problem than others. What does this mean?